# reCaptcha is not display correctly in the Bootstrap Login Modal registration form

Tags: 7, bootstrap-theme

I am using the [Bootstrap Login Modal](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_login_modal) module release 7.x-3.2 to create a modal registration form. Unfortunately, the reCaptcha does not display on the registration form until the registration button is clicked. Afterwards the form will close. When you reopen it, reCaptcha will be displayed.
It looks like it is incorrectly added to the form.
If I switch to using default Math captcha it loads first time without problems.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

reCaptcha doesn't display on the registration form
[image: at first load]

reopened form reCaptcha is dispayed
[image: after reopening]

Answer (score 1):

This helps me adding recaptcha in modal forms.

Check this patch.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1463768 in thread number 21.